# Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: mongoose

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    Item.findOne({}, function(err, foundItems){
  
      if (foundItems.length === 0) {
        Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log("Successfully savevd default items to DB.");
          }
        });
        res.redirect("/");
      } else {
        res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems});
      }
    });
  
  });
```

Please let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

> You can get around this using async/await:

```js
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const foundItems = await Item.find();
  if (foundItems.length === 0) {
    await Item.insertMany(defaultItems);
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems });
  }
});
```